# Angular ng-repeat with ng-form, accessing validation in controller

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I am trying to generate an editable list using `ng-repeat`.  I want to remind the user to update any edits before moving on, so I am using `ng-form` to create "nested" forms on the fly because the documentation says I can then use validation on these dynamically created inputs.

While that seems to work within the HTML, I don't see how to access those dynamically created forms and related validation fields in the controller. Specifically, when the user changes the input I use the form $dirty property to bring up a button to tell the user to commit the changes.  So far, so good.  However, once the changes are committed I want to `$setPristine()` on the field to indicate that the changes have been set.  There may be other ways of ensuring that changes are committed on each input before I allow the main form committed, but this was the best I could come up with.

Unfortunately, even though the documentation says that if I name the ng-form it will be propagated to the `$scope` object, I can't find a way to access it.  `$scope.dynamic_form` is undefined.

Here is a plunker showing what I mean:

[plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/L9rNMNwaVm8noNZeKwnC)

Thanks!

[EDIT] Just to add to the issue, what does work for this specific example is to add to the `ng-click` on the dynamically created input:

```
ng-click="namesForm.name.$setPristine();clean()"
```

But I still don't have access to the dynamically created form in the controller.  I would like, for example, to add a watcher to the `namesForm.name.$pristine` so that I can set the `mainForm.$setValidity(false)` whenever the sub-form is `$dirty` to prevent the user from submitting the main form until all sub-form changes have been committed.

So in a nutshell, the issue is how to access in a parent controller the validation values of a dynamically created nested ngForm?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Updated 2015-01-17:**

As pointed out by Leblanc Meneses in the comments **Angular 1.3** now supports interpolation with `form`, `ngForm` and `input` directives.

This means that using expressions to name your elements:

```
<div ng-form="namesForm_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text"
           name="input_{{$index}}_0"></input>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

will work as expected:

```
$scope['namesForm_0']
$scope.namesForm_1

// Access nested form elements:
$scope.namesForm_1.input_1_0
...
```

---

**Original answer for Angular <= 1.2:**

Working with forms and the `ngFormController` can get tricky pretty quickly.

You need to be aware that you can dynamically add form elements and inputs but they can't be dynamically **named** - interpolation does not work in the `ngForm` or `name` directives.

For example, if you tried to name your nested forms dynamically like this:

```
<div ng-form="namesForm_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="name in names">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Instead of making all the nested forms available on the scope like this: `scope['namesForm_0']` you would only have access to the single (last) form with the literal name `scope['namesForm_{{$index}}']`.

In your situation you need to create a custom directive that will be added along with `ngForm`to handle setting `$pristine$` and `$invalid` for that form instance.

**JavaScript:**

This directive will watch the `$dirty` state of its form to set the `$validity` to prevent submission when dirty and handle setting the `$pristine` state when the 'clean' button is pressed.

```
app.directive('formCleaner', function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: '^form',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.clean = function () {
                scope.namesForm.$setPristine();
            };

            scope.$watch('namesForm.$dirty', function(isDirty){
                scope.namesForm.$setValidity('name', !isDirty);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

Then the only change to your HTML is to add the `formCleaner` directive.

So change your original HTML from this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="mainForm" submit="submit()">
        <h3>My Editable List</h3>
        <div ng-form="namesForm"
             ng-repeat="name in names">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

to this, by adding `form-cleaner` next to `ng-form`:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="mainForm" submit="submit()">
        <h3>My Editable List</h3>

        <!-- Add the `form-cleaner` directive to the element with `ng-form` -->
        <div form-cleaner
             ng-form="namesForm"
             ng-repeat="name in names">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is an updated Plunker showing the new behaviour: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lxem5HJXe0UCvslqbJr3?p=preview

Comment: today interpolation works - see source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L496  - you can get $dirty $invalid states for specific nested ngForm by name.  A lot of possibilities.

Comment: @LeblancMeneses Thanks for that, it looks like interpolation support was added in Angular 1.3.

Comment: Thanks. However, support for interpolation within ngForm and <input name=""> appears to be of limited value in solving this problem if you're using ngMessages. ng-messages does *not* support interpolation, so there's no way to refer to a specific form within an ngMessages element - it just throws an error.

Comment: Dynamically created forms are not available in the controller. Sometime only if scope variable are declared in the controller are available from view to controller. I am getting undefined for the dynamically created variables while accessing

Comment: @JeevaJsb you have to use a name like `myforms.namesForm_{{$index}}` and initialize it in the controller `$scope.myforms = {}` so the reference will not be broken and you can use it correctly.

Comment: exactly in what version of Angular 1.3, interpolation started to be supported?

Comment: @xxlali The dynamic interpolation is available in all Angular 1.3.0+ releases (it was added in 1.3.0-rc.3 so was available as soon as 1.3.0 was "fully" released).