# AngularJS ng-form within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I have a page, with a number of items (rendered through ng-repeat), each one of these items holds a bunch of "read-only" data and a form.

I'm using the ng-form directive and naming them as in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020503/angular-ng-repeat-with-ng-form-accessing-validation-in-controller)

However where mine differs is I'm not putting ng-form on the repeated element as it doesn't "feel right" to have all the display fields/divs inside that form.

Instead my html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <div ng-repeat="inst in Repeats">
  {{inst.name}}
  <div>Loads of "read only" content here, including charts/custom directives</div>
  <ng-form name=frm_{{$index}}>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inst.name" />
  </ng-form>
 </div>
<input type="button" value="View scope in console" ng-click="View()" />
```

The problem is that I cannot get access to the forms on the scope in the controller. The answer to the question (linked above) shows that this naming convention works and I should see a number of objects on the $scope in the controller to get access to.

However as demonstrated in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCPIfJvxEhJAJZaNbkvg?p=preview) clicking the "View scope in console" button - shows the forms have not been added to the scope.

Do I need to change the structure of the html to have both the ng-repeat and ng-form on the same element for this to work??

Comment: Do you have `id` or something unique for these names?

Comment: Scopes are most often than not created based on HTML hierarchy. In your case the form object are part of scopes created due to ng-repeat. Not the parent scope.

Comment: you can try like this also -  <div  ng-repeat="inst in Repeats" ng-form="frmName >

Comment: @EdwardKnowles - the $index keeps the form name unique

Comment: @Chandermani - wouldn't that be the case in the linked example then - or does having both directives on the same element get round this some way?

Comment: @neda - thanks - that's exactly what I was suggesting in the last paragraph and linked question - I'm currently treating that as a last resort (for reasons mentioned in the question)

Comment: @ry8806 my question was is there something originally in the models which you can use to track and not use $index ?

Comment: there is, however I've just tried it in the plunk and it doesn't seem to help matters. It doesn't look like the issue is with the ng-form name - however I might be wrong!

Comment: Having both directive on the same most probably will not work as, the directive priority of ng-repeat is high. It will create a new scope before the form directive gets to do its work.

Comment: I have updated your plunkr and created a adhoc solution to pull out forms from the inner repeat. Check here http://plnkr.co/edit/cVprvMAIsoWQuTKGIW1i?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've solved this.

What I did, which after looking around seems to be a fairly "standard" way of doing it, was to pass the form into the View() function on every call.

the html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <div ng-repeat="inst in Repeats">
  {{inst.name}}
  <div>Loads of "read only" content here, including charts/custom directives</div>
  <ng-form name=frmInputs}>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inst.name" />
  </ng-form>
 </div>
<input type="button" value="View scope in console" ng-click="View(frmInputs)" />
```

Note that the form does not get an "Unique name" in terms of the page (I'm not using {{$index}} to append to the form name anymore) - however as the ng-form is within a repeat - it is unique for each instance in that repeat. So I can pass "frmInputs" to the View() method on my controller - which will allow me access to the form that is currently being acted on.

Comment: If I understand you, shouldn't the <input> be *inside* the ng-repeat <div>? Currently it is *outside* that <div>?